# Consume a rest webservice and persist the content to the database in mule

Tags: mule

I hit a rest webservice and get a JSON object as below:

```
{
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "observations" : [ {
    "id" : 2743,
    "sensor" : "RedBus-11",
    "privacy" : "public",
    "record" : [ {
      "output" : [ {
        "name" : "temperature",
        "value" : "35.0",
        "type" : "DECIMAL"
      } ],
      "starttime" : "06-JUN-2014 11:09:39 IST",
      "position-global" : {
        "latitude" : "19.066680908203125",
        "longitude" : "72.86734008789062",
        "altitude" : "2m"
      }
    } ]
  }]
}
```

On converting the JSON to object, I get a linked HashMap. I need to persist the content in the linked hashmap like altitude, starttime, latitude to MySQL database but am only able to persist the value of linked hashmap in database. Request anyone to help.

My config file is as below:

```
<jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL" user="user" password="password" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTDB"    transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"></jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source>
<jdbc-ee:connector name="MySQL_JDBC_Connector" dataSource-ref="MySQL" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertRecord" value="INSERT INTO TEMP(A1) VALUES(#[message.payload])"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1" doc:name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1">   
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"></http:inbound-endpoint>

    <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="REST Webservice"></http:rest-service-component>

    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"></json:json-to-object-transformer>

    <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.observations]" doc:name="Expression"></expression-transformer>

    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="MySQL_JDBC_Connector" doc:name="Destination"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint> 

</flow>
```

Please advise how this can be achieved in mule.

Comment: You only have one column in your MySQL table, so how do you expect to store all three values?

Comment: I have depicted the use of only one value as an example whereby only the value in the map gets persisted and not individual elements in the map. If you want to only use one element then use latitude in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for the quick response. Mule & MEL expressions is new to me. I tried the option you suggested but am running into issues. My SQL query is: -INSERT INTO ABC(ID, Datetime) VALUES (ID, #[message.payload.observations.['record'].starttime]). The flow has been modified as  <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Expression"></expression-transformer><foreach  doc:name="For Each" collection="#message.payload.observations]"><jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint as before></foreach>.[Error: unterminated string literal][Near:{...message.....'record'].starttime ....}]

Comment: This is great Anirban. Please suggest what changes to make in the flow if the result from the REST webservice is a JSON object with a list of observations. Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small issue in the JSON file .. the element **position-global** has a **-** in it.. so I have changed the element to **positionglobal** .. Now it's working fine .. I am able to insert each element value individually using MEL expression .. Also printed each of the value of elements in console by Logger using MEL .. Now all the elements value can be extracted using MEL .. The only issue is the **-** in the element **position-global** and if you remove that **-** from it ..it will extract **positionglobal** value... Now You can extract and insert whichever value you need to insert into DB from this example :-

```
<jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL" user="user" password="password" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTDB"    transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"></jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="MySQL_JDBC_Connector" dataSource-ref="MySQL" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"> 
        <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertRecord" value="INSERT INTO TEMP(A1) VALUES(#[message.payload.observations[0].id],#[message.payload.observations[0].sensor],#[message.payload.observations[0].privacy],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].name],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].value],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].type],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].starttime],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.latitude],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.longitude],#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.altitude])"></jdbc-ee:query>  
    </jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1" doc:name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1">   
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"></http:inbound-endpoint>

<http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="REST Webservice"></http:rest-service-component>

       <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>

            <logger message="ID:- #[message.payload.observations[0].id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="SENSOR #[message.payload.observations[0].sensor]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="PRIVACY #[message.payload.observations[0].privacy]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="NAME #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="VALUE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].value]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <logger message="TYPE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].type]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
            <logger message="STARTTIME #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].starttime]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>       
            <logger message="LATITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.latitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
            <logger message="LONGITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.longitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>       
            <logger message="ALTITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.altitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        


<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="MySQL_JDBC_Connector" doc:name="Destination"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint> 

    </flow>
```

**UPDATED for LIST of OBSERVATION:-**

```
 <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">

        <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertQuery" value="INSERT INTO TEMP(A1) VALUES(#[payload.id],#[payload.sensor],#[payload.privacy],#[payload.record[0].output[0].name],#[payload.record[0].output[0].value],#[payload.record[0].output[0].type],#[payload.record[0].starttime],#[payload.record[0].positionglobal.latitude],#[payload.record[0].positionglobal.longitude],#[payload.record[0].positionglobal.altitude])"/> 

    </jdbc-ee:connector>  

    <flow name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1" doc:name="MuleRESTExperimentFlow1">   
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"></http:inbound-endpoint>

    <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="REST Webservice"></http:rest-service-component>

           <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>

                <logger message="ID:- #[message.payload.observations[0].id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <logger message="SENSOR #[message.payload.observations[0].sensor]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <logger message="PRIVACY #[message.payload.observations[0].privacy]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <logger message="NAME #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <logger message="VALUE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].value]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <logger message="TYPE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].output[0].type]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
                <logger message="STARTTIME #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].starttime]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>       
                <logger message="LATITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.latitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
                <logger message="LONGITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.longitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>       
                <logger message="ALTITUDE #[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].positionglobal.altitude]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        

    <foreach collection="#[message.payload.observations]" doc:name="For Each">                     
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="MySQL_JDBC_Connector" doc:name="Destination"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint> 
       </foreach>   

        </flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As requested earlier please suggest the changes to be made to the flow if the JSON object returned from the REST webservice is a list of observations. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to persist the values extracted from the Json request .. you can refer the flow and use the MEL expression given .. I have given all the MEL expression to extract the values from all the Json elements .. you can refer this example to insert whatever value you required .. all the values are extracted using the MEL expression ..

Comment: Definitely Anirban. Thank you so much for extracting each element from the JSON object and persisting it. I was just curious to know if we have a way in using MEL to persist a collection e.g. in this case a list of observations and the changes we will need to make in the flow to accommodate it.

Comment: Check my UPDATED for LIST of OBSERVATION... You need to use for each in the flow as well as need to change the JDBC query a bit at the top ......I have updated my answer .. Pls accept my answer if it is useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's blocking you.

Once you have the `Map` payload (the fact it's a `LinkedHashMap` makes no difference), you can use MEL expressions like:

```
#[message.payload.observations[0].record[0].['position-global'].altitude]
```

to read field values.